# Alert dialog issue

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am showing an Alert dialog which just works fine, but I've seen on the internet that most of them use `dialog.show();` at the bottom of the method. Mine is almost at the top and if I move it to bottom, It does crash and it says like; textview is null etc, but works fine if the `dialog.show();` is at the top.

my question is; can I leave it like that? or can this become a problem later? below u can see mine Alert dialog method:

```
public void startSendMessageDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(UserActivity.this);

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.send_message_dialog, null));
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        dialogSendMessage = builder.create();
        Window window = dialogSendMessage.getWindow();
        assert window != null;
        window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        window.getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation;
        sendMessageDialogActive = true;
        **dialogSendMessage.show();**
        btn_send_message_dialog = dialogSendMessage.findViewById(R.id.btn_send_message_dialog);
        MaterialButton btn_send_message_dialog_close = dialogSendMessage.findViewById(R.id.btn_send_message_dialog_close);
        message_desc_tv = dialogSendMessage.findViewById(R.id.message_desc_tv);
        message_succes_lay = dialogSendMessage.findViewById(R.id.message_succes_lay);
        message_send_lay = dialogSendMessage.findViewById(R.id.message_send_lay);
        MaterialButton btn_send_message_get_points = dialogSendMessage.findViewById(R.id.btn_send_message_get_points);
        message_no_point_lay = dialogSendMessage.findViewById(R.id.message_no_point_lay);
        tv_message_title = dialogSendMessage.findViewById(R.id.tv_message_title);
        int prefPoints = Integer.parseInt(SharedPrefManager.getMyPoints());
        boolean premium = SharedPrefManager.getMyPremium();

        if (!premium && prefPoints < 1) {
            tv_message_title.setText("Oh No!");
            message_send_lay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            message_succes_lay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            message_no_point_lay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            dialogSendMessage.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);

            btn_send_message_get_points.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    closeSendMessageDialog();
                    Intent intentStore = new Intent(UserActivity.this, PointsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intentStore);
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
                    finish();
                }
            });

            dialogSendMessage.setOnDismissListener(dialog -> sendMessageDialogActive = false);
            return;
        }


        tv_message_title.setText("Message " + getIntent().getExtras().getString("fname_name"));
        message_desc_tv.requestFocus();
        message_desc_tv.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new MaxLinesInputFilter(4)});



        btn_send_message_dialog_close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                closeSendMessageDialog();
            }
        });

        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
                getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if(imm != null){
            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT, 0);
        }

        dialogSendMessage.setOnDismissListener(dialog -> sendMessageDialogActive = false);

        dialogSendMessage.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
        dialogSendMessage.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
    }
```

Comment: If that shows up as you expect, then that should be fine.

Comment: Also, please show your exact logcat error.